# How to speed up Drupal 7 compiling PHP to C++?

Tags: 7, performance, staging

I would like to improve Drupal 7 performance with [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/) or any other similar solution transforming the code from PHP to C++ or C.

What steps are needed to properly do the scenario below ?

I would like to :

1. maintain @development environment as not-compiled php, adding and
   testing contrib and custom modules.
2. after testing @development, I do rsync @development to @staging
   ...
3. ... and compile @staging
4. test @staging
5. rsync @staging to @life

I think it is a bit oversimplification but should bring an overview.

If it is not possible, are there any other options ?

Comment: I found an article about this subject http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/09/drupal-and-hiphop-for-php-part-i-compilation/ but this still doesn't answer fully my question.

Comment: The last I heard, D7 was not possible with Hip-Hop - but see http://tag1consulting.com/blog/drupal-performance-next-step - and you should post your question in the High Performance group, http://groups.drupal.org/high-performance and ask people there. I'm sure Killes knows the current status. http://drupal.org/user/83

Comment: on the same site as that link refineo posted, there's a D7 hiphop vs APC benchmarking post, so it must be possible with core at least - http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/17/drupal-hiphop-for-php-vs-apc-benchmark/

Comment: Do you have any experience with HipHop and Drupal 7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [link](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/06/30/drupal-hh7-project-hiphop-for-php-and-drupal-7-4-compatibility-patch/) to the complete solution article where webtutor.pl shows how Drupal 7.4 compiled using HipHop for PHP is "up to 6 times faster than in a pure PHP environment".

[Here](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/17/drupal-hiphop-for-php-vs-apc-benchmark/) are the benchmark test results comparing standalone Drupal vs Drupal with APC vs Drupal compiled using HipHop for PHP.

Comment: For the record, I very much doubt this is stable enough for a production site. As you can see there, this requires a large patch which has only been tested against 7.4 and all contrib modules that you want to use require manual adjustments and many will probably not work at all (for example, everything that uses eval()).

Answer (score 5):

Following the chain from [a comment on this great Wordpress tutorial on the new HHVM](http://www.hiphop-php.com/wp/?p=113#comment-599), I was led to Nick Veenhof's blog where he posted very recently about his unsuccessful efforts to get hiphop-php working with Drupal.

For what it's worth, the awesome maintainer of hiphop, Sara Goleman, said in the comments that she was interested in supporting Drupal and was going to try to reproduce the issue.

I'm working at building a vagrant VM to help reproduce the error and get everyone on the same page as easily as possible. The plan is to [use a patch that supposedly worked against Drupal 7.4, and hopefully move forward from that working state :)

https://github.com/patcon/vagrant-hiphop-drupal